# Element goes out of the screen

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="@string/errore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_btn"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share_green" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I should put the `ImageButton` at the right of the `Textview`, but if I change the `orientation` to `horizontal`, the button sometimes (depends from the text in the `Textview`) isn't visible.
How can I fix?

Thank you.
*PS: sorry for any error, I'm Italian `:(`*

Answer (score 0):

Make your textView of fixed width instead of wrap_content. Insert a blank view between textview and imageview so that imageview stays at the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="@string/errore"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share_green" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't optimized for all screen's dimension

Comment: Check my edits, this will allot 2/3 space to the textview and 1/3 to the imageview of the total width.

Comment: There isn't a "more mathematical" way? Also utilizing tables...
Thanks :)